# bootstrap validator doesn't want reset

Tags: angularjs, bootstrapvalidator

I have a problem with bootstrap validator,
i have a angularjs project where i have a form in a modal in a directive.
so, i want when the modal hides, reset the form to the validator reset.
But when i use :

```
$('#StandardForm').bootstrapValidator('resetForm', true);
```

nothing is happening, when i recall my form modal, the validators is always here.(the inputs are green(good) or red(not good)).

see my directive :

```
angular.module('app.administration').directive('wcStandardForm',['servicesHTTP', function(servicesHTTP)
{
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
        standard: '=',
        method: '&'
    },
    replace: true,
    templateUrl: 'app/administration/directives/standard/wc-standard-form.tpl.html',
    link: function(scope, form)
    {
        form.bootstrapValidator({
            framework: 'bootstrap',
            excluded: ':disabled',
            feedbackIcons: {
                valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
                invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
                validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
            },
            fields: {
                name: {
                    validators: {
                        notEmpty: {
                            message: 'le nom est nécessaire.'
                        },
                        stringLength: {
                            max: 31,
                            message: 'Le nom ne doit pas dépasser 31 caractères.'
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    },
    controller: function($scope)
    {

        /**
         * Vide le moduleForm
         */
        $scope.clearStandardForm = function()
        {
            //$scope.standard = {};
            $('#StandardForm').bootstrapValidator('resetForm', true);
        };

        /**
         * Valide le module et envoi la requete http
         */
        $scope.validateStandardForm = function()
        {
            ...
            $scope.clearStandardForm();
        };
    }
};
}]);
```

and here the template :

```
<div class="modal fade" id="standardFormModal">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">
                    <span aria-hidden="true" ng-click="clearStandardForm()">&times;</span>
                    <span  ng-click="clearStandardForm()" class="sr-only">Close</span>
                </button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Assigner fonctions</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form id="StandardForm" method="post" class="ng-pristine ng-valid bv-form" novalidate="novalidate">
                    <button type="submit" class="bv-hidden-submit" style="display: none; width: 0px; height: 0px;"></button>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label">Nom</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" ng-model="standard.standard_name">
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-actions">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" ng-click="clearStandardForm()">Close</button>
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"data-dismiss="modal" ng-click="validateStandardForm()"><i class="fa fa-save"></i> Sauvegarder</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->
```

I tried to do the `$('#StandardForm').bootstrapValidator('resetForm', true);` on the event `show.bs.modal` et `hidden.bs.modal` of the modal and the same things.

So if you have a idea, i will take it :)

Comment: is this typo mistake `<form id="StandardF orm"` there is space in `Form` where in JS the selector to rest the form `$('#StandardForm').bootstrapValidator('resetForm', true);`

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code, found this mistake `id="StandardF orm"` (if it's not typo)

```
<form id="StandardF orm" method="post" class="ng-pristine ng-valid bv-form" novalidate="novalidate">
```

Where the selector use in JS is `$('#StandardForm')`

Second if you look at the Reference [here](http://bv.doc.javake.cn/api/#reset-form), alternate way to resets the form fields which have validator rules is `$(form).data('bootstrapValidator').resetForm();`

```
$('#StandardForm').data('bootstrapValidator').resetForm(true);
```